# create migration and model together but add prefix to the migration name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, laravel-migrations, artisan-migrate

I want to create model and migration together like:

```
php artisan make:model Models/Program -m
```

However, I want to name migration as `pas_programs` and not `programs`

Is there any way?

Comment: do u means all the same prefix?

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to set different prefixes for each migration or will there only be one or two prefixes that you're going to use?

Comment: same prefix as 'pas'